# What <form:xxx> tag should be used when outputting data?

Tags: spring-mvc

When displaying information about my student from the database, I use the Spring MVC `<form:xxx>` tags, but I don't know how to display it simply in a cell, I don't use input tags, textarea tags, etc. For some reason it doesn't work otherwise. It looks like this now:[image]

and I need this information to be just in the cell, I also attach my output code:

```html
 <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3"
                       style="font-size: small; line-height: 25px; border-color: #D1EEEE">

                    <tr bgcolor="#DCDCDC" align="left" style="border-color: #838B83">
                        <th width="100px">Name</th>
                        <th width="230px">Surname</th>
                        <th width="270px">Group</th>
                        <th width="220px">Date of enrollment</th>
                    </tr>

                    <form:form action="studentProgress" modelAttribute="student">

                        <form:hidden path="id"/>
                        <tr valign="bottom">

                            <td style="padding-bottom: 20px"><form:form path="name"/></td>
                            <td style="padding-bottom: 20px"><form:input path="surname"/></td>
                            <td style="padding-bottom: 20px"><form:select path="group"/></td>
                            <td style="padding-bottom: 20px"><form:textarea path="date"/></td>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </form:form>


                </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was found, it was necessary to place my data between the tags

and the information began to be displayed correctly :

```html
   <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3"
                       style="font-size: small; line-height: 25px; border-color: #D1EEEE">

                    <tr bgcolor="#DCDCDC" align="left" style="border-color: #838B83">
                        <th width="100px">Name</th>
                        <th width="230px">Surname</th>
                        <th width="270px">Group</th>
                        <th width="220px">Date of enrollment</th>
                    </tr>

                    <form:form action="studentProgress" modelAttribute="student">

                        <form:hidden path="id"/>
                        <tr valign="bottom">

                            <td style="padding-bottom: 20px"><p>${student.name}</p></td>
                            <td style="padding-bottom: 20px"><p>${student.surname}</p></td>
                            <td style="padding-bottom: 20px"><p>${student.group}</p></td>
                            <td style="padding-bottom: 20px"><p>${student.date}</p></td>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </form:form>


                </table>
```

[image]